# How can I make a gradient border around a circle in react-native? I am using LinearGradient but it fills in the circle instead

Tags: react-native, linear-gradients

[image]

I want the black border to be gradient and I want the circle to be transparent.
Is there a separate library I can use or is there a way to go around this?

```
<LinearGradient
            colors={['#00FFFF', '#17C8FF', '#329BFF', '#4C64FF', '#6536FF', '#8000FF']}
            start={{x: 0.0, y: 1.0}} end={{x: 1.0, y: 1.0}}
            style={styles.CircleShapeView}
        >

        </LinearGradient>


    CircleShapeView: {
        position: 'absolute', 
        top: 1, 
        left:50, 
        right: 0, 
        bottom: 0, 
        width: Dimensions.get('window').height /3,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height /3,
        borderRadius: Dimensions.get('window').height / 2,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderWidth: 5,
        borderColor: 'black',

      },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not give it as border but you can create a view inside of linear gradient to get the same effect.

Here is a snack where you can test it: https://snack.expo.dev/@truetiem/border-gradient

```js
<LinearGradient
  colors={['#00FFFF', '#17C8FF', '#329BFF', '#4C64FF', '#6536FF', '#8000FF']}
  start={{ x: 0.0, y: 1.0 }}
  end={{ x: 1.0, y: 1.0 }}
  style={{
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    borderRadius: 100,
    padding: 5, // This should be the border width you want to have
    overflow: 'hidden',
  }}>
  <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      borderRadius: 100,
      backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}>
    <Text>Your content goes here</Text>
  </View>
</LinearGradient>
```

Comment: So I'm using React Native CLI and not React Native Expo. Does this make any difference? I imported it from "import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';"

Comment: Looks like it didnt matter I just need to adjust the size and position. It works! Thank you!!